# Database for Poll + Explanation which can be updated

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I've got the following poll form for my users but I am not sure how I should structure the DB around it.

The user will get 20-30 poll questions like the following:

### What is your favorite color?

- Blue
- Green
- Yellow
- Red
- Other

Will be able to choose one of the above answers and `must also provide around 100 words` explaining why he chose that answer.

I've currently got two tables. One that holds the poll questions and one that holds the poll options. What I am not sure about is how should I hold the user answers.

The thing is because the poll is so big, the user can do it partially, come back at a later time, alter his answers and keep going until he is 100% done which is then that I'll be able to view the whole result in my panel. So he can basically save his progress and alter it at anytime. On top of that I would like to "remove" the whole poll for a specific user and be able to redo it all over again but at the same time keep a history of his previous answers.

So I am not sure if a table like this would be the best option for my needs:

```
id
user_id
poll_questiond
poll_answer
poll_text
last_update
status
```

Seems like something like this will create a huge mess. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create 3 tables:

**table_polls**

```
+----+---------------------+--------+
| id |     description     | status |
+----+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | Example description |      1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+
```

**table_poll_options**

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | poll_id | description |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | Question 1  |
|  2 |       1 | Question 2  |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

**table_poll_answers**

```
+----+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | option_id | user_id |  description   |     created_at      |
+----+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 | A valid reason | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  1 |         2 |       2 | Another reason | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
```

To recapitulate the above:

A poll *has many* questions.

A poll question *has many* answers

A poll answer *has one* user.

---

This way you have everything split up with pivot tables and you no longer need to create messy rows in your poll table.

You can expand on the tables of course, if you need extra information for dates etc.

Comment: Nice touch the option_id :) I was just wondering if this approach will be messy if the users keep editing their answers etc Plus I will need a way to disable/remove their whole answers while keeping a backup at the same time.

Comment: @Bravo, instead of physically deleting the answer row upon the using deleting their answer. You can add an extra column status or deleted_at. If this field is either 0 or has a datetime then do not include them in your poll calculations and do not show them to the users. While if you're an admin or have enough privileges then show those answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find it easier if you define your problem domain in semi-structured language. You may decide to delegate some of the logic to the application layer, rather than embedding in the database schema - for instance, saving partially-completed polls might be easier within the application layer.

You might start with something like this, capturing the major entities in your domain, and their relationships, but not their attributes.

> The system consists of many **polls**.
>
> One **poll** has many **questions**. A **question** belongs to 1
>   **poll**.
>
> A **question** can be of type **multiple choice (select one)** or
>   **multiple choice (select n)** or **free text**
>
> A **question** may be **mandatory** or **optional**
>
> A **multiple choice question** has 1..n **answer options**
>
> A **question** has a sequential relationship to other **questions**
>   (e.g. the free text question must follow the favourite colour
>   question)
>
> The system consists of many **users**
>
> A **user** answers many **polls**
>
> When the user **answers a poll**, they answer 0..n **questions**
>
> When the user **answers a poll**, the **answer** is only valid if the
>   user completes all **mandatory questions**

This suggests that you have two polymorphic entities - question (which can be free text or multiple choice), and answer (as the answer is related to the question, it is also free text or multiple choice).

You have to decide how to model this in your schema - Stack Overflow has many questions on this topic - but I'll pick the simplest.

```
Poll
-----
Poll_id

Question
------
Question_id
Poll_id
Sequence
Is_mandatory
Description

Question_option
-------------
Question_option_id
Question_id
Option_id
Sequence
Description

User
-----
User_id

Poll_session
------
Poll_session_id
User_id
Poll_id
Date
Status

Poll_session_answer
-----
Poll_session_id
Quesion_id
Free_text_answer
Question_option_id_answer
```